# web config rewrite rule to force http to https on multi tenancy application

Tags: asp.net

i have a multi tenancy portal system but the rewrite rule is not working on multiple conditions

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
<add input="{HTTPS1}" pattern="^(website1\.com|www\.website1\.com)$" />
<add input="{HTTPS2}" pattern="^(website2\.com|www\.website2\.com)$" />
<add input="{HTTPS3}" pattern="^(website3\.com|www\.website3\.com)$" />
<add input="{HTTPS4}" pattern="^(website4\.com|www\.website4\.com)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />

    </rule>
```

I expect That when i visit http://portal.website1.com on my webs browser, that the program should take me to https://portal.website1.com and to do the same for portal.website2.com, portal.website3.com,portal.website4.com

but it only works for portal.website2.com and portal.website3.com , it does not force https on portal.website1.com and portal.website4.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `system.WebServer`:

```
 <system.webServer>
....

    <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URO}" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```